# Pass column names to Hadoop Hive streaming job

Tags: hadoop, streaming, hive

I'm writing a Hadoop streaming job in Hive and I'd like my streaming script to be aware of the column names of the table that it's receiving. I've tried setting `set hive.cli.print.header=true;` but this prints the names to the console without making them available to the script (so far as I can tell).

Ideally, I'd also be able to make the data types available as well.

Is there an option in the Hadoop Streaming API or in Hive that will allow me to capture the column names in the streaming job?

*Update:* I am able to extract Hadoop environment variables as well as set arbitrary variables from my Hive script and have them available in my streaming script. I am investigating whether access to these environment variables will allow me to access the data column names or pass them in a hacky fashion.

Comment: What do you need this for??? Why do you need specific column names? I do not understand your requirements clearly

Comment: @NicoleHu I need this so that I can interact with the columns by their names. Without the names then I have to know the order of the columns, which is hard to keep track of and susceptible to breaking as soon as I change the schema in any way.

Answer (score 3):

I am submitting an answer but this will work only if the "initial" data contains the column name ie. data should have some sort of key-value pairs structure. You can now store the input type with a map structure in hive and query based on keys. I will give you an example.

Say you have a file in hdfs at location '/user/input' with data as following

```
A B C1=D1:C2=D2:C3=D3:C7=D4
E F C1=H1:C7=H2:C5=H4
```

Perform the following in hive :

```
hive>> create external table my_external_table 
       (column1 string, column2 string, my_map map<string,string>) 
       row format delimited 
       fields terminated by ' ' 
       collection items terminated by ':' 
       map keys terminated by '=' 
       lines terminated by '\n' 
       stored as textfile location '/user/input';
hive>> select * from my_external_table;
result>> A B {"C1":"D1","C2":"D2","C3":"D3","C7":"D4"}
         E F {"C1":"H1","C7":"H2","C5":"H4"}
```

Now you can perform queries as such

```
hive >> select map_keys[my_map] from my_external_table;
result >> ["C1","C2","C3","C7"]
hive >> select map_values[my_map] from my_external_table;
result >> ["D1","D2","D3","D4"]
          ["H1","H2","H3","H4"]
hive >> select "C1",my_map['C1'] from my_external_table;
result >> C1    D1
          C1    H1
hive >> select map("C1",my_map['C1']) from my_external_table;
result >> {"C1":"D1"}
          {"C1":"H1"}
```

And supposedly you want to create a new table with some existing map key-values, do the following :

```
hive >> create table my_new_table as select map('C1',my_map['C1'],'C2',my_map['C2']) from my_external_table;
hive >> select * from my_new_table;
result >> {"C1":"D1","C2":"D2"}
          {"C1":"H1","C2":null}
```

**Hence, using the above method I can create new tables to store the key names along with the value names as well as perform any sort of transformations on them ,provided, the initial data is stored as key-value pair.**

**Note** :

1. You can easily create a script which will add the column names as needed into your hive query.
2. Suppose your "initial" data doesnt contain column names, you can either convert your data to contain column names. Or, you can use a custom mapper to echo out the data as key-value pairs
3. I have kept my own delimiters, feel free to change as per need.
4. You need not have column1 and column2 also. I just kept it to show you that all the data need not be key-value pairs